# Different api responses for same object values

Tags: go, go-echo

This is the code example:

```
func GetValue(c echo.Context) error {
    //other implementation details
    
    value, err := service.GetValue()
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, errorresponse.Error(4003, err))
    }

    //if I set same value here, it works as expected
    //value.Value = []int8{48, 48, 48, 54, 54, 49, 56, 54, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32}

    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, value)
}
 
//this is type service.GetValue() returns
type ValueGetResponse struct {
    Value     interface{}
    ValueType string
}
```

If I use the value which comes from `service.GetValue()` method, the API gives me a response like bellow. It converts it to a some kind of string which I don't know. When I check the `value.Value` property, the `reflect.TypeOf(value.Value)` says, it is a `[]int8` as type. Also the VSCode debugger approves it.

**THE OBJECT USED IN REQUEST:**

[image]

**THE RESPONSE:**

```
{
    "Value": "MDAwNjYxODYgICAgICAg",
    "ValueType": "[]uint8"
}
```

If I set expected value manually, it works as expected and I do not understand why the first one is not.

```
value.Value = []int8{48, 48, 48, 54, 54, 49, 56, 54, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32}
```

**THE OBJECT USED IN REQUEST:**

[image]

**THE RESPONSE:**

```
{
    "Value": [
        48,
        48,
        48,
        54,
        54,
        49,
        56,
        54,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32
    ],
    "ValueType": "[]uint8"
}
```

Comment: `int8` & `uint8` aren't one and the same. Also `byte` is an alias of `uint8` so `[]uint8` is probably a byte slice. That means that `"MDAwNjYxODYgICAgICAg"` is the correct value, the slice of *int8s* is most probably *not*.

Comment: I missed that point. You seems right

Comment: Is there any way to get this value as array, not as string ?@mkopriva

Comment: You'd have to type-assert the `Value` field and then convert it to something that gets marshaled into the format that you want. E.g. https://play.golang.org/p/AjDYhlmN3R6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Golang `byte` is alias for `uint8` and when you use `json.Marshal` it returns `[]byte` which is same type as your data. So when you receive this type of data it is translated to string.

You need to cast uint8 to other int type or implement `Marshaler interface`

**Cast**

```golang
bytes, err := service.GetValue()
value := make([]int8, 0)
for _, v := range bytes {
    value = append(value, int8(v))
}
```

**Marshaler**

```
type CustomType []uint8

func (u CustomType) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var result string
    if u == nil {
        result = "null"
    } else {
        result = strings.Join(strings.Fields(fmt.Sprintf("%d", u)), ",")
    }
    return []byte(result), nil
}

func GetValue(c echo.Context) error {
    var value CustomType
    bytes, err := service.GetValue()
    value = bytes

    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, value)
}
```